# MSSQL - Merging Several Databases into a Single Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, conditional-statements

I hope someone can help me out, looked around but most of the posts regarding this seem to not quite be what I'm looking to do.
Im running MSSQL 2008 Standard.

I have setup 3 databases each one gathers various details from 3 VM's.
Basic structure is

```
DataBase: VM1 - Table:WEB
Server_Name    Date          STATE
VM1            01-06-2013    ONLINE
VM1            02-06-2013    ONLINE


DataBase: VM2 - Table:WEB
Server_Name    Date          STATE
VM2            01-06-2013    ONLINE
VM2            02-06-2013    OFFLINE

DataBase: VM3 - Table:WEB
Server_Name    Date          STATE
VM3            01-06-2013    OFFLINE
VM3            02-06-2013    OFFLINE
```

From these I want to have them all placed into 1 Database daily, but everytime I do im getting Duplicated Data.
I found if i Tried in SSIS I can, but then each of the Tables one by one doing the Merge then Conditional Split. but that gets incredibly complex eventually. (I have a Table defined for each Process, reason being is each is basically a Import from a application LOG, nothing complex, its just like JAVA, MC, TeamSpeak, etc.) each of the VM's are my little Testing, Developing and Live systems.

Is there a Easier way to do a Merge of any changed data from the 3 Databases to the New Consolidation Database?